# install ubuntu 16.04 failed

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, cd

I want to ask if there is an error when installing Ubuntu 16.04 in what CD do I do?

[image: screenshot of "Load installer components from CD" dialog]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Your image shows a read-error on your install-media, which can be because it was removed (why it asks you to ensure it's in your drive), the disk is bad (verify it & create/use another if there are issues), or the drive is failing (and just can't read the data on that disk). I would suggest checking integrity of the install-media (if a new disk, I'm assuming you verified the download before writing; but if you didn't do that, I'd suggest do that first!). Reboot and hit <space> when you see keyboard & person-in-circle pic, then a menu shows.

Answer (score 0):

Your CD has a failed iso image.

Before burning a CD with the ISO image, please check the image.

To verify I suggest you read this article: https://www.howtogeek.com/246332/how-to-verify-a-downloaded-linux-iso-file-wasnt-tampered-with/

To record the CD you can read this article: https://www.tutonics.com/2012/07/how-to-create-bootable-live-cddvd.html